# A problem on matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

[image]

I know that $$e^{M}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{M^k}{k!}$$ But from this I stuck

Comment: It might help to note that $\int_0^1 \exp(tA)\,dt = A^{-1}[\exp(A) - I]$

Comment: Have you tried looking computing the blocks of $M^k$?

Answer (score 4):

Using the power series definition is probably the neatest approach for this problem in any case. Verify (by induction, perhaps) that for $k \geq 1$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^k = \begin{bmatrix}
A^k & A^{k-1}B\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Thus, conclude that
$$
\exp\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^k/k! & \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^{k-1}/k! \right)B\\0 & I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
With that, it suffices to verify that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1}/k!$ is the power series corresponding to the function $f(x) = \int_0^1 \exp(tx)\,dt$.

---

*Below is an incomplete attempt at an alternative approach*

As an alternative, we could use the IVP definition of the matrix exponential, which is to say that the function $\Phi:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^{(n+m) \times (n+m)}$ given by $\Phi(x) = \exp(Mx)$ satisfies $\frac{d\Phi}{dx} = M\Phi$ and $\Phi(0) = I$.

With that in mind, define
$$
\Phi(x) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\exp(Ax) & x \int_0^1 \exp(txA)\,dt \cdot B\\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Note that $\frac d{dx}\exp(xA) = A\exp(xA)$, and using integration by parts compute
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac d{dx}\int_0^1 \exp(txA)\,dt &= 
\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \exp(txA)\,dt
\\ & = 
\int_0^1 tA \exp(txA)\,dt
\\ & = \left[(t/x)\exp(txA) \right]_{t = 0}^1 - \int_0^1 \frac 1x \exp(txA)\,dt
\\ & = \frac 1x\left[\exp(xA) - \int_0^1\exp(txA)\,dt\right]
\end{align*}
$$
Thus, with the product rule, we have
$$
\frac d{dx}x\int_0^1 \exp(txA)\,dt = 1\cdot \int_0^1 \exp(txA)\,dt + x \cdot \frac 1x \left[\exp(xA) - \int_0^1\exp(txA)\,dt\right]
\\ = \exp(xA).
$$
With that, we find
$$
\frac d{dx}\Phi(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
A \exp(xA) & \exp(xA) B\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: A detail that is easy to correct  : there is an $I$ matrix in the lower right corner of the result the asker wants to reach.

Comment: @Jean Fixed, thank you